# Cloth not touching surface

Tags: cloth-simulation

i'm trying to get a tablecloth on a table but it kind of stays above without touching, how can i fix that please ?[image: hovering cloth]

Answer (score 2):

Change the collision distance. There are distance settings in the Cloth, and also in the collision object. The total distance will be the two combined. Try adjusting both.

Comment: Thanks, that's it, just found out before reading your post )))